# font awesome 4.7 upgrade in Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, font-awesome

I have been using font awesome with Visual Studio 2013. I installed in through the NuGet Package manager.

Today i notice Font Awesome 4.7 has been released with some very useful icons. NuGet package manager shows no updates available. I downloaded FA 4.7 myself and extracted the fonts and css files, over writing the existing files in my project (and refreshed folder).

However i cannot get the new icons to appear. If i use the code for the new icons, nothing appears at all when i run my page. All older icons are still showing.

AFAIK, i only need the one line, in my master page, referencing the font awesome css file. Nothing there needs changed.

Comment: have u try to clean cache on browser? sometime css and font are cached on browser.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. I uninstalled the package through Nuget Manager in Visual Studio, and reinstalled it. Seemed to work after that. 4.7 isnt available through visual studio but seemed to pick the 4.7 files up that i had added to the solution.